# Find if lat/long point is inside an area

Tags: openstreetmap, latitude-longitude, php, point-in-polygon

I have got data using [OpenStreetMaps Ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way) of many areas.  I would now like to write a function which would return "true or false" if an single latitude/longitude point is found in that area or not.

I have already seen many answers to this question such as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950062/checking-if-a-longitude-latitude-coordinate-resides-inside-a-complex-polygon-in) however none of these deal with the issue when the Greenwich meridian line is crossed.  Most of my area searches will occur in London which means I need a function that can cope with both negative and positive values for the lat/long points in the area.

Is there a known way on how to solve this?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Currently I'm using PHP but the language doesn't matter too much (I'm sure I can convert a function in almost any language to PHP)

Comment: how is your data stored? in postgres?

Comment: MySql db.  Values stored as JSON in a string field

Comment: http://turfjs.org/docs#booleanPointInPolygon

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter if the Greenwich meridian (longitude = 0) is crossed. The standard point-in-polygon algorithms work with both positive and negative values for coordinates. The only difficulty is if the polygon has lines which cross the anti-Greenwich meridian (longitude = plus or minus 180) and which therefore jump from -180 to +180.

My solution is to convert both the polygon and the point to be tested into the Lambert azimuthal equal-area projection, centred at the North Pole, then use the [Horman-Agathos algorithm](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/4ffe/636eadc2dc6459089a0edd0a671302d7f676.pdf) to see if the point is in the polygon. This is fine as long as the polygon doesn't contain the South pole, which in practice is unlikely.